# i need redirect my page after excution

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

after Execute this page database is updated value but does not redirect my page then view white blank page please fix my problem sir

```html
<?
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $pro_id = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $pro_id2 = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $login_qry = "UPDATE images SET img3_b='0' WHERE img3_b='$pro_id'";
    $login_result = mysql_query($login_qry) or die(mysql_error());

    if($login_result){
        header('Location: updateimages2.php?id='.$pro_id2);
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Image Details Not Updated Retry Again');";
        echo 'window.location.href = "manageusers.php";';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your full code, so that we can help your in better way. ?

Comment: What does the error log say?

Answer (score 0):

Add the upper part on page;

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

and change your this code;

```
header('Location: updateimages2.php?id='.$pro_id2.'');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to display echo before you redirect to the page then let page wait for some time

header('Refresh: 3;url=your-page.php');